# How to exit text files/logs when viewing them in Putty

Tags: putty, tail, logfiles

I'm new to putty. Connected to a linux server to view/read some files.
So, I opened a text log file that is constantly being updated, so I'm getting new lines every second.

Is there a shortcut/command to exit/close the file when viewing in putty?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It was not "vim", but "tail -f" that I was talking about. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Erm... shouldn't you mention what program you are using? vi/vim doesn't support continuous monitoring. So, it is like `tail -f` or `less` in (F)ollow mode?

Comment: Yes, like I said: I'm new. Hench, I didn't know what I was talking about. It was "tail -f" that was running, not vim. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I've edited your question for you. Also, voted to move to [SU]. Welcome to [SO]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Ctrl+C is the shortcut.